# Tomcat, Apache : Failover not working even after configuration

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing, failover

I am working on Apache and tomcat to setup Load-balancing and fail-over. Initially I thought that `load-balancing` would include `fail-over`, but I was wrong. I thought that if one instance is not active, then consuming other instance also becomes a part of load-management. Enough with the terminologies, I setup fail-over, but the ironical part is `fail-over` itself is failing.

As soon as I shut down one instance of tomcat, the entire setup is dead and I am getting 503. Can someone help me understand what is the problem.

Added this in apache2.conf :

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties

JkMount /* loadbalancer
```

workers.properties :

GNU nano 2.2.6                               File: workers.properties

```
 worker.list=loadbalancer
 worker.server1.port=8010
 worker.server1.host=localhost
 worker.server1.type=ajp13

 worker.server2.port=8011
 worker.server2.host=localhost
 worker.server2.type=ajp13

 worker.server1.lbfactor=1
 worker.server2.lbfactor=1

 worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
 worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=server1,server2
worker.loadbalancer.method=B
worker.balancer.sticky_session=True
```

000-default in sites-enabled :

```
JkMountCopy On
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8010 route=server1 connectiontimeout=10
    BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8011 route=server2 connectiontimeout=10

   ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from none
   Allow from all

</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests off

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
</VirtualHost>

<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from none
Allow from all
</Location>
```

First tomcat's server.xml :

```
<Connector port="8080" proxyPort="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" compression="force" compressionMinSize="1024" 
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>


<Connector port="443" enableLookups="false" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compression="force"
              compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS"
                keystoreFile="keystore_file" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
   <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server1">
    // No modifications inside
</Engine>
```

Second Tomcat's server.xml :

```
<Connector port="8081" proxyPort="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" compression="force" compressionMinSize="1024" 
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>


<Connector port="443" enableLookups="false" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compression="force"
              compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS"
                keystoreFile="keystore_file" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
 <Connector port="8011" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server2">
    // No modifications here
    </Engine>
```

What mistake I am making in the config for implementing load-balancing and fail-over together. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using two different proxy modules, dont do that.

One is mod_jk, and the configuration files are workers.properties, uriworkermap.properties and in apache.conf this part:

```
JkMount /* loadbalancer
```

And in 000-default

```
JkMountCopy On
```

The other is mod_proxy and the relative configuration in 000-default :

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8010 route=server1 connectiontimeout=10
    BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8011 route=server2 connectiontimeout=10

    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from all

    </Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ProxyRequests off

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
</VirtualHost>

<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from none
Allow from all
</Location>
```

As for comments, let's go the mod_jk route. First remove the mod_proxy configuration part, essentially all that is in 000-default leaving only:

```
JkMountCopy On
```

Then disable loading of this modules (not neccessary but better):

mod_proxy_*

Then add this to you'r loadbalancer's worker in workers.properties:

worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session_force = false

And check if things work, based on that i'll update the answer

Comment: I don't mind using mod_jk sir. But the answer you have posted contains the config I have, kindly suggest me with mod_jk if you find that convenient. THanks a lot. :-)#

Comment: Then first make sure you have a working mod_jk config, start removing mod_proxy's directives that i noted in my reply and check if things still work, based on thet i'll update the answer

Comment: Yes, I have that module. I also called apache2ctl -M and its output is here : http://pastebin.com/DxxPuLJG  . Should I remove everything from 000-default, because the file was empty before

Comment: See answer, i'll keep updating that as i can format there

Comment: The update is in the end, essentialy just remove the mod_proxy modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97424/discussion-between-fredi-and-we-are-borg).